# Backe-End cart making

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, ssms

I have made Product table in database . So When user clicks Add to cart , the products should be added in cart table . i have made cart page . but i don't know after fetching product name how to isnsert the particular product into cart table in database when user clicks add to cart. till now i have made product description,name and price on every individual web page . so please anyone can show code or teach me how the cart works in back-end with help of database and how product name , ID & price gets transferred to cart. i used JSP,JQuery,CSS,HTML[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww2sg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNIdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I quite didnt get your question, but i noticed you are using local storage for something. All you have to do is set up a query to your database to insert an item based on its ID, having an API which will "listen" to your requests and do whatever you need to do - insert, delete, get, etc - on your database. When i get home later i can share a small part of a code i wrote envolving an fake e-commerce and its communication with API/Db, its Angular2(front), NodeJS (back) and Mongo (Db), but at least you can have an idea of what you need to do.

Edit: i got it on github, dah.
Respositories: ecommerce and ecommerceAPI. I hope it helps a little.
https://github.com/BrunoSM90

Comment: I want to make Add to cart but i want to make full functionality of cart in back-end process